# Can not get the result of RadioButton onchecked() in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, ischecked

I can't get values to return. Application force closes on *Agree* button click. I can't get the values back from i_am.isChecked() for all other radio buttons.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RadioButton i_am,practic,read_terms;
    i_am=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.first);
    practice=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.second);
    read_terms=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.third);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.termandconditionxml);

    Button agree_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Agree);
    agree_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checker()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done all cliked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Termsandcondition.this)
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage("Please verify ")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",null).show();

            }
        }

        private boolean checker() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("iamanhcp"+i_am.isChecked());
            if(i_am.isChecked()) {
                System.out.println("iahcp"+i_am.isChecked());
                if(practice.isChecked()) {  
                    System.out.println("iama"+practice.isChecked());    
                    if(read_terms.isChecked()) {    
                        System.out.println("iama"+read_terms.isChecked());
                        return true;    
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }


    });
}//oncreate end
```

============================

```
07-05 15:36:14.301: W/dalvikvm(1702): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.andoid.Termsandcondition$1.checker(Termsandcondition.java:53)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.andoid.Termsandcondition$1.onClick(Termsandcondition.java:36)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-05 15:36:14.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you share the error detail from LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

May be it force close because of your `getApplicationContext` in your `Toast`. Use `this` instead.
To get values from your `RadioButton`s, use the `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "done all cliked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and

```
    i_am.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Hope this helped you.